# wrong wp-admin redirect when setting up wordpress inside subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I setup my wordpress in a docker container, use nginx reverse proxy to forward all requests of location `/blog` to that docker container.

The problem is after logging in to wp-admin, it redirected to `domain/wp-admin/` instead of `/domain/blog/wp-admin`.

What's the problem? I've set `WP_SITE_URL` and `WP_HOME` to `/blog`

Comment: Maybe you need to set rewritebase in htaccess

Comment: @NaveedRamzan: I found the problem is because it redirects to the `wp-admin-canonical` url which doesn't include `/blog`, I don't know why `wp-admin-canonical` value is wrong

Comment: ok that's nice that you have debugged yourself.

Comment: https://github.com/roots/trellis/issues/236

Comment: @Vasim Vanzara Thanks for the comment but I don't see the answer there

Comment: ok,can you please share a url?

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did to fix it:

```
// add these lines to wp-config.php
define('WP_SITE_URL', 'http://domain.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://domain.com/blog');

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: I'm running into similar problem trying to deploy docker/container to url/path .  But inside my container, the files are all in /var/www/html and not sub-dir.  Is your install also in the root html dir or in subdir /blog?

Comment: I think you want to define WP_SITEURL variable instead of WP_SITE_URL

Comment: Thank you. That helped me. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great solution, saved my day!