# nginx subpath to redirect to wordpress docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, proxypass

#### Background

I am working on adding a Dockerized blog stack (Wordpress + MariaDB) to our existing website that runs on Nginx. `location /` already serves out the website, and I have been instructed to add logic to the Nginx config where `/blog` redirects all traffic to the Docker container.

#### Attempt 1

- I started the wordpress container at `localhost:9999` on the server.
- Using the references I added additional logic:

`location ^~ /blog {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }`

**Problem:**

Wordpress redirected `http://server/blog` to `http://wp-admin/install.php`, and since there was no rule for this I got a 404.

#### Attempt 2

I changed the `location` to process `/blog` as well as any URL containing `wp-.*`. The assumption is that all Wordpress pages will have that URL.

`location ~ ^/(blog|wp-.*) {`

This worked through the Wordpress setup. 
And if I explicitly visit `http://server/wp-admin` I am able to go to the blog admin pages.

**Problem:**

- The Wordpress blog pages do not satisfy the regexes above, and return a 404. e.g. `http://server/?p=31` is a link to a blog post.

#### Attempt 3

Just for the heck of it I redirected `location /` to the Docker container and the blog works perfectly. But that is not the problem statement I have, sadly.

#### Question

What do I do next, in order to serve all wordpress-specific requests from? I feel I am getting into a loop of fighting regexes when there might be a more elegant solution here.

#### References

1. [nginx proxy pass subpaths not redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423414/nginx-proxy-pass-subpaths-not-redirected)
2. [How can I have same rule for two locations in NGINX config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320674/how-can-i-have-same-rule-for-two-locations-in-nginx-config)
3. [nginx redirect to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265396/nginx-redirect-to-docker-container)

Answer (score 6):

According to a self-answered SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41479776/1264360

```
// add these lines to wp-config.php
define('WP_SITE_URL', 'http://example.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/blog');

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` is where it's at, thank you.

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer to help others in the future

Comment: @vish  would you do the honors if this answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to have your wordpress website accessible via `wp` subdirectory. For example:

http://your-website.com/wp

Here is how I managed to get this working without altering wp-config.php. The key is to use `working_dir` directive.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

 nginx:
   image: nginx:1.17
   container_name: nginx
   restart: unless-stopped
   depends_on:
     - wordpress
   ports:
     - '80:80'
   networks:
     - app-network
   volumes:
     - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

 db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   container_name: db
   volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   networks:
     - app-network

 wordpress:
   container_name: wordpress
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: wordpress:latest
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
   working_dir: /var/www/html/wp
   volumes:
    - wordpress:/var/www/html/wp
   networks:
     - app-network

networks:
 app-network:
   driver: bridge

volumes:
 db_data:
 wordpress:
```

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /wp/ {
            proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://wordpress;
        }
     }
}
```